# Generar una orden de rastreo numérica en mysql

Tags: mysql

Hola intente generar una llave única para un listado de ordenes que fueran numéricas con un máximo de 6 numeros aleatorios no repetitivos.

En el query tengo lo siguiente el problema es que esta se repite:

```
$data = Order::select(
                DB::raw('CONCAT(ROUND(RAND() * POW(8, 3))) as clave_rastreo'), //Llave unica de rastreo
                'c.clabe',
                'cd.nombreMarca as beneficiario',
                DB::raw('COALESCE(c.rfc,"XAXX010101000") as rfc'),
                DB::raw('SUM((op_cobro_detalle.precio * op_cobro_detalle.cantidad)  - (op_cobro_detalle.montoYappPD * op_cobro_detalle.cantidad) ) as monto'),
                DB::raw('CONCAT("Yapp Cash","") as concepto'),
                DB::raw('CONCAT("YAPP1","") as empresa'),
                DB::raw('CONCAT(COALESCE(nombre,"")," ", COALESCE(apellido_paterno,"")," ", COALESCE(apellido_materno,"")) AS nombre')
            )
            ->join('op_cobro_detalle', function($join)
                {
                    $join->on('op_pedido.idPedido', '=', 'op_cobro_detalle.detallable_id');
                    $join->on('op_pedido.idRestaurante','=', 'op_cobro_detalle.idRestaurante');
                })
            ->join('op_carrito','op_pedido.idCarrito','=','op_carrito.idCarrito')
            ->join('sys_usuario_individual as c','op_carrito.idUsuario','=','c.idUsuario')
            ->join('sys_cliente_data as cd','op_carrito.idUsuario','=','c.idUsuario')
            ->join('sys_usuario as r','c.idUsuario','=','r.idUsuario')
            ->whereIn('op_pedido.estatus',self::$status)
            ->whereIn('op_pedido.tipoPedido',self::$typeOfOrder)
            ->where('op_cobro_detalle.detallable_type','Pedido')
            ->whereIn('r.idRol',$idRol)
            ->groupBy('c.idUsuario', 'c.clabe', 'beneficiario', 'c.rfc');
```

Answer (score 0):

Para quienes les pueda servir aqui les dejo mi solución:

```
CONCAT(LPAD(FLOOR(RAND() * 999999.99), 6, 0)) as clave_rastreo

+--------+
| Value  |
+--------+
| 499540 |
| 550607 |
| 254419 |
| 620272 |
| 338104 |
| 829705 |
+--------+
```

De esta manera pude lograr lo requerido.